# How to use Gradle's Manifest API to insert a `MANIFEST.MF` file into the root of a zip file

Tags: manifest, gradle

We use the `manifest` attribute of the java plugin to write `MANIFEST.MF` files to our `jar` artifacts.

We also use gradle to build `GWT` projects and the output we've defined for those projects is a `zip`. I'd like to include a `MANIFEST.MF` file in the root of that zip file.

I've tried using a task of `type: Jar` so I can use its `manifest` property but the problem, of course, is that the manifest file is written into `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, which I don't want. The reason is that we unzip the archive into the main app and I need to be able to reference the `MANIFEST.MF` file at runtime for my own nefarious purposes.

So right now the archive looks like this:

```
/gwtdirectory/
/gwtdirectory/file1
/gwtdirectory/file2
/gwtdirectory/...
/gwtdirectory/filen
```

And I need it took like this:

```
/gwtdirectory/
/gwtdirectory/MANIFEST.MF
/gwtdirectory/file1
/gwtdirectory/file2
/gwtdirectory/...
/gwtdirectory/filen
```

I've already successfully gotten it to look like:

```
/gwtdirectory/
/gwtdirectory/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
/gwtdirectory/file1
/gwtdirectory/file2
/gwtdirectory/...
/gwtdirectory/filen
```

Through a definition like:

```
task pack(type: Jar){
  manifest {
    attributes(...)
  }
  extension = 'zip'
  from gwt.destinationDir
}
```

The [`writeTo`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/java/archives/Manifest.html#writeTo(java.lang.Object)) method looks mighty promising, except I can't find an implementation of that interface that I can use and I'm trying to avoid writing my own.

Thoughts?

Comment: `Jar` task has `getManifest()` which returns the `Manifest` implementation. So I guess you should be able to do `pack(type:Jar){ manifest.writeTo(...) }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Jar task](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.groovy), it does not look like the location of the manifest file is configurable.

You may want to use gradle's own [DefaultManifest](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/java/archives/internal/DefaultManifest.java) implementation to create a manifest and then include this file with `from` in your zip file.

You can try this:

```
import org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest
import org.gradle.api.internal.file.IdentityFileResolver

File manifestFile = file('build/myAwesomeManifest.mf')

task generateManifest << {
   manifest = new DefaultManifest(new IdentityFileResolver())

   // add some attributes
   manifest.attributes(["attr1":"value1", "attr2":"value2"])

   // write it to a file
   manifest.writeTo(manifestFile)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there is exactly what you are looking for at the end of [this chapter](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N1230C) from Gradle manual.

```gradle
jar.manifest.writeTo("$buildDir/mymanifest.mf")
```

Comment: I have tried above solution, but it didn't work, can you please add some example